# Send key in Flink Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Flink Stream processing, and need some help with Flink Kafka producer as cannot find much related to it after some time of searching. I am currently reading stream from a Kafka topic and then after performing some calculation I want to write this to new a seperate topic in Kafka. But the problem I am facing is that I cannot send key to the Kafka topic. I am using Flink Kafka connector which gives me FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer. For more detailed look below is my code, what can I change in my code that it could work, currently on Kafka that I am producing my message are going with null in Key where as the value is what that I need:

```
Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();
    
    consumerProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", serverURL);
    consumerProperties.setProperty("group.id", groupID);
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(consumerTopicName,
            new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerProperties);

    kafkaConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
    DataStream<String> kafkaConsumerStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
    final int[] tVoteCount = {0};
    
    DataStream<String> kafkaProducerStream = kafkaConsumerStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String map(String value) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.readValue(value, JsonNode.class);
            Tcount = Tcount + jsonNode.get(key1).asInt();
            int nameCandidate = jsonNode.get(key2).asInt();
            System.out.println(Tcount);
            String tCountT = Integer.toString(Tcount);
            //tVoteCount = tVoteCount + voteCount;
             
            //waitForEventTime(timeStamp);
            return tCountT;
        }
    });
    kafkaConsumerStream.print();
    System.out.println("sdjknvksjdnv"+Tcount);
    Properties producerProperties = new Properties();
    producerProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", serverURL);
    FlinkKafkaProducer<String> kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(producerTopicName,
            new SimpleStringSchema(), producerProperties);
    kafkaProducerStream.addSink(kafkaProducer);
    env.execute();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-flink-with-kafka-consumer-and-producer) you will find an example on how to write key and topic into a topic:

You need to replace your creation of a `new FlinkKafkaProducer` with something like below:

```java
FlinkKafkaProducer<KafkaRecord> kafkaProducer = 
  new FlinkKafkaProducer<KafkaRecord>(
    producerTopicName, 
    ((record, timestamp) -> new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(producerTopicName, record.key.getBytes(), record.value.getBytes())), 
    producerProperties
  );
```

Comment: Hello mike. Your message was a lot of help. But I need a little bit more help. The solution you provided group by the values based on the key. But when a message arrives and there is no other message with same key then the calculations is not performed and the same message is published over at Producer Topic. Is there a way where the new messages could also be send with my custom key and the calculations are performed? Thanks

Comment: Hi @QasimKhan, apologies I am not completely familiar with it. Please ask a new question clarifying exactly what you are trying to achieve and how your current code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your own [KafkaSerializationSchema](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/KafkaSerializationSchema.html) rather than using a `SimpleStringSchema`, then you will have complete control over what's written. @mike has provided an example of how to do that in his answer.